# Delete line only if previous line has tag - sed ? or easier?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, xml

I'm facing a rather newbie problem and caught my ears around it :(
I have a file with xml tags and I want that when I find:

```
    </ac:image>
  </a>
```

the `</ac:image>` one followed by an `</a>`, then to delete the line with `</a>`.

There was also an "a href" before but that one was rather specific and I deleted it with sed and a match.
On this one I wonder how to approach it, if it's a multiline match but then not sure how to select the second line of the match.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: FYI, XML is *impossible* to parse with 100% reliability using regular expressions.  This is a mathematical fact, not hyperbole.  You might get "good enough for most purposes" but you will (provably) not be able to handle all valid XML input.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577108/5419599 for examples.

Comment: taking a look now but this isn't really the case from that link.
while this is xml, in reality what I want to replace always looks the same and there won't be any false positives with a regexp.
it is in fact confluence page where initially I did copy paste of images from a locally hosted tiny web server. I was expecting confluence to add / upload images... it did links instead. Now I saw how a link to a locally uploaded attachment looks but I need to filter out what it added (the a href part and there is one more tag that I could already replace with sed).

Comment: If this is generated XML, then your reality is subject to change if any setting in Confluence changes.

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the same sequence without surprises, you don't need XML parsing and you can indeed use `sed`.

To always check a pair of two lines, use the `N;P;D` pattern in `sed`:

```
sed 'N;P;\_</ac:image>\n *</a>$_d;D' filename
```

How does it work?

- `N` appends the next line. Usually you do `$!N` to check whether there is a next line at all, but that's no problem in your case: If there is no next line, nothing special happens.
- Now that you have two lines in your buffer, `P` prints the first line
- `\_</ac:image>\n *</a>$_d` `d`eletes the pattern space if you find the given pattern of two lines (the `\n` is the newline between the lines). The first line was already printed, so deleting the pattern space only drops the second line of the pair
- The last statement is only executed if the pattern didn't match. The `D` deletes the first line (and the newline) and restarts the cycle with the second line of the pair, so each pair of lines is checked

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
gsed '/<\/ac:image>/,+1 { /<\/a>$/d; }' testfile.txt
```

where `gsed` stands for GNU `sed`.

Comment: Why not add a little explanation? Not everybody knows a range with `+1` and not everybody understands that you need `{}` to use an address inside a range. Thank you.